# Java. Чтение с COM-порта

Tags: java, com-порт

Есть большие промышленные весы, данные с них приходят на компьютер на com-порт. На компьютере крутится программа, которая получает данные с com-порта и пишет в лог.

Необходимо параллельно подключиться к этому порту, получать данные и пересылать на определенный адрес.
Использую библиотеку jssc.

```
SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1"); //объявляем  
serialPort.openPort(); //открываем  
serialPort.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0);// задаем параметры  
String from_port = serialPort.readString(); // читаем
```

и вот тут скрипт ждет, пока данные поступят на вход. Поступили,отправили.

```
serialPort.closePort(); // закрыли
```

В результате мы получили данные и скрипт завершился. А мне-то надо дальше слушать com-порт...

Я наверно не догадываюсь о каком-то простом решении... Ну не **while (true) {}** же использовать)

И такой вопрос, когда я отрыл порт программно, будет ли он доступен программе, которая получает эти данные и пишет в лог?

Answer (score 4):

> Ну не while (true) {} же использовать)

используйте что то вида

```
need_stop = true;
while (serialPort.IsOpen && !need_stop) {
   //..
}
```

need_stop - это специальное булевое поле, которое может быть выставлено в false, если нужно завершить работу с портом (к примеру, пользователь решил закрыть программу).

Comment: @KoVadim , Я больше переживаю за : когда я буду получать данные с com-порта, весы смогут передать на него данные и программа сможет получить с него данные? Сама суть в том, что бы читать параллельно, не нарушая текущий процесс.

Comment: @Автостопом_до_Рая ИМХО в таком случае, процесс работы с периферийными устройствами на COM портах нужно делать в отдельном потоке. Это даст возможность не лочить интерфейс пользователя, если например в цикле while (serialPort.IsOpen && !need_stop) { ... } будет ожидаение данных.

Answer (score 0):

У класса SerialPort есть метод getInputBufferBytesCount().
Соответственно, если он возвращает не 0, то буфер не пуст и надо данные забрать, если 0, то программа продолжается без каких либо тормозов.