# Запуск программы по сигналу с COM порта Java/C++

Tags: java, c++

Есть задача по сигналу с COM порта открывать и запускать файл для печати, то есть если приходит сигнал 0, то игнорируем, а если 1 то запускаем сценарий, раньше с COM портами дела не имел поэтому нахожусь в затупе, не понимаю окончательно как реализовать, заранее спасибо

Comment: А как начально пытались реализовать?

Comment: а кто этот сигнал в COM порт будет присылать? Просто так "сигнал 0/1" не существует.

Comment: изначально долго пытался сделать через C++, но найденные решения от блаблакод не помогло
сигнал в COM будет присылать кнопка или датчик с ардуинки, с ними тоже раньше не сталкивался, но основная задача сейчас сделать так, чтобы при получении сигнала открывалось приложение и в нем уже выполнялось действие (печать файла)

Comment: Не, так не бывает, чтобы при получении сигнала по com-порту система загружала какой-то код. У вас изначально что -то должно быть загружено в память (сервис, приложение) и слушать соответствующий порт (не абы какой, а конкретный). Если на С++, то рекомендую Qt/QSerialPort, на Java тоже полно примеров https://stackoverflow.com/a/901015/4711135

Comment: @Vl13  Любое решение не будет работать, пока Вы не определитесь с протоколом. Можно конечно проверять, есть ли сигнал на определенной ножке ком порта, но это не нужно, лучше сделайте ардуинку, которая будет проверять кнопку (или что там будет) и посылать в компорт байтики регулярно. А уже приложение будет проверять и реагировать.

Comment: глобально как я вижу: 1.мне надо открыть порт(это вроде понял как сделать) 
2. слушать COM 
3. если пришел определенный сигнал, то выполнить задачу, то есть открыть файл 

то есть сигнал приходит и внутри кода выполняется условие для открытия файла

Comment: @KoVadim вот именно это мне и надо, видимо я не до конца корректно сформулировал, вот мне и нужен код который бы слушал и правильно реагировал, не понимаю как это сделать

Comment: слушать порт - это просто читать с порта байт за байтом и анализировать.

Comment: Вот прямо справа ссылки с вопросами про com-порт https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/401234/235611